# How can I get all my stuff to transfer with my world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I transferred a world over from my Switch to my PC using Realms. However, nothing I had on the world is backed up. Is there a way for me to get everything I had on the world to transfer too?

**Edit:** I have figured out how to do it.

Comment: Could you post an answer explaining how you did it? This would help anyone who has the same question in the future. If you have any reference links or videos that you used and can post them that would be great.